# $f\colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $f(x)=\int_0^xf(y)~dy.$

Tags: real-analysis, integral-equations

I faced the problem that says:

> If $f\colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $f(x)=\int_0^xf(y)~dy.$ Then which of the following option is correct?
>   $1.f(x)=e^x$
>   $2.f(x)=\ln(x)$
>   $3.f$ is identically $0$
>   $4.f$ is identically $1$.

My attempt: Here,$f'(x)=f(x)$ and so finally we can come $f(x)=Ae^x, A$ being a constant.So,option $1$ looks right.Am I right? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You need to prove that $f$ is differentiable. Also, option 3 is possible.

Comment: The easiest way to solve the problem is to just try the four functions and see if any of then fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is the Riemann integral of the continuous function $f$, it follows that $f$ is differentiable and has derivative $f$.  So, as you say, $f'(x)=f(x)$, so $f(x)=A e^x$ for some constant $A$.  However we also have $f(0)=\int_0^0 f(y) dy=0$.  Therefore $A$ must be $0$, so $f$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ is identically zero then also all conditions of the problem are satisfied which makes it to be one of the solution.